# How to have a Promise forward the type of an overloaded function it calls to its own caller?

Tags: typescript

I've extended an EventEmitter class and used function overloading so that, when calling addListener with a specific string, the callback will be automatically typed:

```
const codes = {
    code1: 'code1',
    code2: 'code2',
} as const;

type CodeType = typeof codes;

interface Code1Interface { a: string };
interface Code2Interface { b: boolean };

class MyEmitter { // extends ...
    public addListener(code: CodeType['code1'], callback: (event: Code1Interface) => void): void;
    public addListener(code: CodeType['code2'], callback: (event: Code2Interface) => void): void;
    public addListener(code: CodeType[keyof CodeType], callback: (event: any) => void): void; // fallback
    public addListener(code: any, callback: any) {
        // call the parent addListener here
    }
}
```

However, I have a function that encapsulates the addListener into a promise and TypeScript can't guess the return type:

```
function getEvent(code: CodeType[keyof CodeType]) { // returns Promise<unknown>
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const emitter = new MyEmitter();
        emitter.addListener(code, (event) => resolve(event));
    })
}

getEvent(codes.code1).then(x => x) // x has type unknown
```

Is it possible to forward the type of the interface defined in the function overloading to the caller of the getEvent function or do a more generic mapping that can be reused in the MyEmitter class?

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=57#code/MYewdgzgLgBKAmBTCMC8MDeAoGu4iQEYAuGAcgUULIBoc9KAmUigxR2rAXxgEMVQkKAG4sWKAE8ADohgBhNgBVps9JJkgAZviQRRWAJZgoiAE6bewWQqIBJY2YtXMfUtFNGA5jC6ijJ80trNkZ7AKdZDBgAI1JokBAAG0ReMB99YET+FABZCQBRAFsDKACXAHpymEQADxMweBQAOhb6XCkAV2jEg2A+eHgAGQNoRDAzAApKUhtEZRkAbVYiMgBdGjheRMToywBrUgnEADcxqBm2QjDHIIBKNAA+GGOQA3hb0he30TwYTu7ev0hiN6pNpvIlColkw1htgFsdvtDiczhckKEHIErPdUE8vu9Pq94D88P8en1eANhqNxqYpmw0XMoXtEBItBCkPNEOtNttdsADjAJi0mrxTJ4IKRUhIFqscU9pR9nkThDBKjALHz9m0-l1yUDqaC6eDpXCEfzBYrMDrfur4dsYFAABayKRis4GkFjMwwF2mRA6rjcMSaDpgYBQAzgGCeRBQfKnYz0pCMrkLFls7SzLly62-f1QDqmNLjADuMAACqYQMUIIgJhN-RAkqcNv6AFaICPyvO-BjgaDVYqlH3oMswPJFEoBCa3El9ofTsyiqle2nJxAbI6JqA9pst+so4y3OeB27B2PxncbiBNSiEW5NZ1jCY1R4wGr3dVvp38R0qGAwz2MAQFLMAgA)

Comment: You can't really generalize over overloads or manipulate them programmatically.  I would probably write your example using generics instead of overloads.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0vxaw) meet your needs? Note I changed the keys of `codes` to be distinct from the values since making them the same just makes it hard to see which types come from where.,  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, that's almost exactly what I need! I just also need to be able to add more codes (e.g. code3) without needing to update CodeKeyMap right away. That's the reason for the fallback in my demo, although I could have made that clearer.

Comment: @jcalz actually, adding `[key: string]: any` to CodeKeyMap seems to have done the trick! That works perfectly for me, I would be happy to see an explanation of how it works.

Comment: I was just going to suggest doing [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9VQJm) (I don't think you can add it to `CodeKeyMap` so much as `CodeValueMap` but ‍♂️).  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Actually check out Mr. Unicorn's `emittery` , it has something like that https://www.npmjs.com/package/emittery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) do not currently generalize well; they only resolve to the "correct" call signature when you call them directly.  If you try to use higher-order behavior, like type inference, the compiler tends to give up and just pick the last call signature.  This might change sometime, (there's a pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#52944](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/52944) that would improve things if merged), but as of TypeScript 5.1 overloads are hard to manipulate.

For your example code, I'd be inclined to switch from overloads to [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
type CodeValMap = {
    code1: Code1Interface;
    code2: Code2Interface;
    [k: string]: any;
}

class MyEmitter { 
    
    public addListener<K extends keyof CodeValMap>(
      code: K, callback: (event: CodeValMap[K]) => void
    ): void;

    public addListener(code: any, callback: any) {}
}

function getEvent<K extends keyof CodeValMap>(code: K) {
    return new Promise<CodeValMap[K]>((resolve, reject) => {
        const emitter = new MyEmitter();
        emitter.addListener(code, (event) => resolve(event));
    })
}
```

Here we've defined `CodeValMap` to be a map from the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"code1"` and `"code2"` to the corresponding `event` type (and you can add an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) pointing to `any` to get the fallback behavior if you need it).

And `MyEmitter`'s `addListener` is generic in `K extends keyof CodeValMap`, so that it accepts two correlated `code` and `callback` arguments.  Then `getEvent()` is essentially written the same way, as a generic function in `K extends keyof CodeValMap`, and we return a `Promise<CodeValMap[K]>` so that the type of `code` carries through to the return type:

```
getEvent(codes.c1).then(x => x) // (parameter) x: Code1Interface
getEvent(codes.c2).then(y => y) // (parameter) y: Code2Interface
getEvent("hoobydooby").then(z => z) // (parameter) z: any
```

Looks good!

---

Note that it's possible to generate `CodeValMap` programmatically from your `codes` const and a manually-written type mapping from the values of `codes` to the corresponding interfaces, like this:

```
const codes = {
    c1: 'code1',
    c2: 'code2',
} as const;

type CodeType = typeof codes;

interface CodeKeyMap {
    c1: Code1Interface,
    c2: Code2Interface
}

type CodeValMap = {
    [K in keyof CodeType as CodeType[K]]: CodeKeyMap[K]
} & { [k: string]: any }
```

That `CodeValMap` is equivalent to the one written manually, but this form might be more useful if you'd like to keep things written in terms of the keys and not the values of `codes`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKAmBTCMC8MDeAoGu4EYAuGAcgUXxIBoc9gAmYskJe6rAXxgEMVRIoAbixYoATwAOiGAGEWiACqTp6cVJAAzOPIjCsASzBREAJw3dg0uUnwBJI6fOXMPYtBOGA5jA7DDxswsreXp7AKdpDBgAI2JokBAAG0RuMB89f0cg2XkAaUQxAFluCUxaXGAiHJswrMsaPDhGasRQh0DLThE1YKQANW5E4tL0bEaAbVyYQxgAawLNFqUpHhRrRWVJgF0t4nX8opLtzhgAMhdx2bcoDzBPXZ4wMR8RAHoAKhgeloGhkrQyo1yFV1nZ2hFhECQnsQrUOohIXhLtdbvdiKkxCd3q8RFhgIleChCmIAKIAW30UACLlerxgiAAHsYwPAUAA6DnlGASACu0US+mAPHg8AAMvpoIgwKYADxTRnM1lzBZada-YYAPgAFORiLkqHBBolohYrjAtYgAG5SqAw-qDYbbACUaA1MEtIH08CdxA9XsRuF5-MFwrFEuZph18nRTwNwCNJuAZoxLrGjTwtMNiUSXwAFtIJNwTDbQ+LJdKTDB88WuRwulgNDywMAoPpwDBPIgoCTrUY5fSmVKlfMxIs1Q6StrdTBcqmucWoDyTGlpQB3GAABRMIApEEQMvHfwk221WuLECS1oNxYAVogWy7UG60+ntAJ6RSqaYAWuYMTyZSARak6Abpogn4BGy3AimWEYmFGSAGhavZQI+brnpeiDITaTogbWTpdJ23YoQhyBspUTpslA+ZgFqDKujADIupmWqFiY3Bkl2pgugydoUHCERYERPY2qREDkfQlHUVKWrPE+MBiMxdKsUWHFcSYLpiHxbThEEQldiJRhagARLmCTRGI8DmWIxlSTRWoAF4MQ5SnmmxakBC6DkxmIQA)

Comment: I accepted this answer, but I kinda think the code in the post could be more close to the one in the playground. Having the codes in a separate object and doing the `type CodeValMap = { [K in keyof CodeType as CodeType[K]]: CodeKeyMap[K] } & { [k: string]: any }` was a crucial part of solving my issue.

Comment: I will edit the answer to mention how it's possible to build that type programmatically, when I get a chance. Might not be for a few days because I'm primarily on mobile right now

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `Promise<T>` generic parameter somewhere, it can't be inferred from callback functions
I recomment using a type-only `typed-emitter` lib for proper ee types

```
interface Code1Interface { a: string };
interface Code2Interface { b: boolean };

import TypedEmitter from 'typed-emitter'
import EventEmitter from 'node:events'

type MyEvents = {
    code1: (event: Code1Interface) => void
    code2: (event: Code1Interface) => void
}

class MyEmitter extends (EventEmitter as new () => TypedEmitter<MyEvents>) {}

function getEvent<Code extends keyof MyEvents>(code: Code) {
    return new Promise<Parameters<MyEvents[Code]>[0]>((resolve, reject) => {
        const emitter = new MyEmitter();
        emitter.addListener(code, (event) => resolve(event));
    })
}
let x = await getEvent('code1')
//  ^?
// let x: Code1Interface

// placing it into return works as well
function getEvent2<Code extends keyof MyEvents>(code: Code): Promise<Parameters<MyEvents[Code]>[0]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const emitter = new MyEmitter();
        emitter.addListener(code, (event) => resolve(event));
    })
}
```